# Want gallery image to open up to the side rather than beneath

Tags: html, css

```css
.drop {
    display: inline-table;
    
}

.drop-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
   
   
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: 1px solid #333;
    
}


.drop:hover .drop-content {
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
   <div class="drop">
  <img src="storage.jpg" alt="storage" width="200" height="150">
  <div class="drop-content">
  <img src="storage.jpg" alt="storage" width="400" height="300">
  <div class="desc">Large storage space</div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

HTML - It works that when you hover over the image it enlarges below. I would like to get the image to open to the side as opposed to enlarging below. Is this possible?

```
    <div class="drop">
    <img src="storage.jpg" alt="storage" width="200" height="150">
    <div class="drop-content">
    <img src="storage.jpg" alt="storage" width="400" height="300">
    <div class="desc">Large storage space</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 .drop {
  display: inline-table;

    }

.drop-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;


box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border: 1px solid #333;

}


.drop:hover .drop-content {
display: block;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8defzc32/)

I have made changes here:

`.drop:hover .drop-content {
  display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Class drop needs to be position: relative and the drop-content needs two parameter - top: 0; left: 100%;